# How to display its sibling categories when reaching to the deepest level of active category in sidebar?

Tags: shopware6

Here is the current sidebar extended file :
When reaching the deepest level of the category, it should display its siblings where it has no child category available.

```
{% block layout_navigation_categories_list_entry %}
    {% if item.category.id in activeResult.path %}
        {% block layout_navigation_categories_recoursion %}
            {% if item.category.id in activeResult.id %}
                {% set levelIncrement = 1 %}
            {% else %}
                {% set levelIncrement = 0 %}
            {% endif %}
            {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/layout/sidebar/category-navigation.html.twig' with {
                navigationTree: item.children,
                activeResult: activeResult,
                level: level + levelIncrement
            } only %}
        {% endblock %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if (item.category.id in activeResult.id) or (item.category.parentId in activeResult.id) %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can then check the currently iterated category if it has the same parent id as the currently active category (being a sibling of the currently active category).

This should do it:

```
{% block layout_navigation_categories_list_entry %}
    {% if item.category.id in activeResult.path %}
        {# unchanged #}
    {% endif %}
    {% if (item.category.id in activeResult.id) or (item.category.parentId in activeResult.id) or (item.category.parentId == activeResult.parentId) %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```